# how to move imageView with textField for keyboard without scrollview?

Tags: swift, xcode

I create template authorization page with password and login! I placed textfields(password and login) on top of imageView, is it possible to realize that the keyboard does not overlap with the imageView without scrollView?

Comment: Yes. But using a scroll view makes it easier.

Comment: try this https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 2):

When user click textField you can call this function:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
        self.logoImage.center.y = self.logoImage.center.y - 70
        self.searchBar.center.y = self.searchBar.center.y - 70
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

When user stop typing everything will be same before not editing

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
            self.view.bounds.origin.y = 0
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
```

Comment: i don't have searchBar ! a have just imageView and two textFields and button ! Below screenshot https://ru.files.fm/u/ayr26uyc https://ru.files.fm/u/rdfm2e7k

Comment: Dude I named my textField as a searchBar...

Comment: no problem dude by the way can you approve my answer

Comment: I apply this solution, but when I start typing my screen more up and appears black lines in bottom.      objc func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
                             self.view.frame.origin.y -= 150
                             }
                            @objc func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
                             self.view.frame.origin.y += 150
                             }

Comment: can you share screen shot

Comment: yes! https://ufile.io/3gslcbsf

Comment: is that happen when you type password ?

Comment: Password or username

Comment: check my answer again.

Comment: what I should past instead of logoImage and searchBar in your example ?